# Pass cell index path through selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have UICollectionView and on each of cell i want to add a button. When this button clicked i want to remove cell at specific index. Problem is, i don't know how to pass selected index. Here is my cellForRow.. method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    IndexGridCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *str = self.viewModel.arrValues[indexPath.row];
    [cell bindViewModel:str];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:button];

    [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.left.equalTo(cell.mas_left).with.offset(0);
        make.top.equalTo(cell.mas_top).with.offset(0);
        make.width.height.equalTo(@(20));

    }];

    return cell;
}
```

So basically i want to pass index throught  `action:@selector(aMethod)`. How to do that?

Comment: You can't pass it to aMethod because the method signature is fixed. You could use the button's tag since the button will be sent to aMethod as the sender (the selector wil need to be `aMethod:` not `aMethod` but a cleaner approach would be for the button to be part of `IndexGridCollectionCell` and to use delegation to get the button action back to your view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have **only one section** you want to get the index you can add Your `UIButton` Like this

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
[button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:button];
```

And then get its tag number -

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"tag number is = %d",[sender tag]);
    //In this case the tag number of button will be same as your cellIndex.
   // You can make your cell from this.

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

If you have multiple section you may try like this

**Option:1**

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tblView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForCell:cell];//get the indexpath to delete the selected index
```

**Option:2**

```
UIView *contentView = (UIView *)[sender superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];//get the selected cell
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForCell:cell];//get the indexpath to delete the selected index
```